# Не меняется фон кнопки и размер шрифта

Tags: html, css

Добрый день. Возникла проблема с фоном кнопки. Изменяется только цвет и ширина  рамки вокруг нее. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так с кодом.

```css
.but {
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 190px;
  height: 70px;
  background: #CC00CC;
  border-color: #CCCC00;
  font-size: 44px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 13px 0px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border: outset;
  1px #73CFF0;
}
```

```html
<div class="but">
  <input type="button" value="Каталог услуг">
  </input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял, должно быть так:

```
.but input {
   margin-right: auto;
   width: 190px;
   height: 70px;
   background: #CC00CC;
   border-color: #CCCC00;
   font-size: 44px;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-style: italic;
   text-align: center;
   cursor: pointer;
   padding: 13px 0px;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   border: outset 1px #73CFF0;
 }
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Все получилось!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.but, .but input {
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 190px;
  height: 70px;
  background: #CC00CC;
  border-color: #CCCC00;
  font-size: 44px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 13px 0px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border: outset 1px #73CFF0;
}
```

```html
<div class="but">
  <input type="button" value="Каталог услуг">
  </input>
</div>
```

Comment: только почему-то тепеь кнопк по центру располагается, а не п краю, как надо(